# Calculating a periodic signal (way of solving this)?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I created my own examples so i can have the gist of how to solve the real ones that my homework needs so here we go:

$$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \Pi\left({t-4n\over2}\right) + \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty Π{(t-4n)} $$

So i want to find if this singal is periodic and what it's period, can i have a step by step solution (more like understanding)?

What concernes me is how i tackle the sums.

Comment: What is $\Pi?$  Do you mean the number $\pi?$

Comment: no by Π i mean the rectangular function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function

Comment: Okay, what about $Π\frac{(t-4n)}{(2)}?$  Is that supposed to be $$\Pi\left({t-4n\over2}\right)?$$

Comment: well yeah that's it saulspatz.

Comment: The infinite sums are not truly infinite. For any particular $t$, only a finite number (a very low finite number) of the terms are non-zero. So to find the value for $t$, just sum up those few terms. And as a hint, consider what happens if you replace the index $n$ with a new index $m = n+1$.

Comment: Mr.Sinclair can you elaborate further, i am new to all of this to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Let be $f(t)=\Pi(t/2)+\Pi(t)$. So we have
$$
x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(t-4n)
$$
Can you see that $x(t)$ is periodic with period $T=4$?